# Prove that $a^2 + 54a + 981$ can't be divisible by $55$ for some whole number $a$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Prove that the modular congruence
> $$
> a^2 + 54a + 981 \equiv 0  \pmod{55} 
> $$
> has no whole number solutions.

I have tried breaking up the sum, because we know $$981\equiv 46 \mod{55}$$
and
$$54a \equiv-a \pmod{55}$$

But I got stuck at $$a^2$$

Comment: Where did this problem arise? What do you know about problems like this? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please have a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and come back and edit your question. *Without showing more effort in your post, you should not expect quality answers!*

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Completing the square will simplify the problem.

Comment: possible  $\pmod {11}$  but not  $\pmod {5}$

Comment: if you show that this is not divisible by $5$ then the work is over.

Comment: try completing the square as suggested by @Aaron and check the quadratic residues modulo $5$

Answer (score 2):

If $a^2 + 54a + 981 \equiv 0  \pmod{55}$ then $a^2 + 4a + 1 \equiv 0  \pmod{5}$.

Plugging residues into $a^2 + 4a + 1 \pmod{5}$,

$0 \mapsto 1$
$1 \mapsto 1$
$2 \mapsto 3$
$3 \mapsto 2$
$4 \mapsto 3$

So there can be no solutions for $a^2 + 54a + 981 \equiv 0  \pmod{55}$.

Comment: Or (to apply a nuke from orbit) complete the square to obtain $(a+2)^2 \equiv 3 \mod 5$.  Then compute $(\frac{3}{5}) = (\frac{2}{3}) = (\frac{-1}{3}) = -1$.